# duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I tried to add this code into my database
However, it's giving me an error it says that there is a duplicate value 1. And I don't really understand why it tells me this?  for as far as I know there is only one 1.

```
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Machine: localhost
-- Genereertijd: 04 mrt 2013 om 19:05
-- Serverversie: 5.5.24-log
-- PHP-versie: 5.3.13

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Databank: `dressesdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `dresses`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dresses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `roast` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `dresses`
--

INSERT INTO `dresses` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `price`, `image`, `review`) VALUES
(1, 'Galaxy Night', 'Prom dress', 350, 'galaxy.png', 'A beautifull Galaxy dress'),
(2, 'Blue Cloud', 'Prom dress', 200,  'black.png', 'A beautifull blue cloud dress'),
(3, 'Black Night', 'Prom dress', 600, '6380325.png', 'A beautifull black dress'),
(4, 'Red Velvet', 'Prom dress', 400,  'red.png', 'A beautifull red velvet dress');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: `'A beautifull Galaxy dress'')'),` looks faulty

Comment: I know it does however I tried to remove the ') it and it just gives me the same error.

Comment: Removing `')` still makes it faulty, remove `'')`

Comment: remove 'A beautifull Galaxy dress'`')'`),

Comment: sorry it's still not working and still giving me the error even if I remove it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact error you are getting. Does the table already exist and does an entry with id 1 already exist?

Comment: the problem is that the phpmyadmin is in dutch I mean I can try to translate it in English? it tells me: double entry '1' for search key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Please don't say "not working", instead tell is *exactly* what error you're getting. **MySQL is extremely specific about where the failure occurs** so read the errors carefully.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try this:
if you have a column with primary key and auto-incremented value then there is no need to mention the id and value of id in insert statement. remove the id and value of id from query try this:

```
INSERT INTO `dresses` (`name`, `type`, `price`, `image`, `review`) VALUES
('Galaxy Night', 'Prom dress', 350, 'galaxy.png', 'A beautifull Galaxy dress'),
('Blue Cloud', 'Prom dress', 200,  'black.png', 'A beautifull blue cloud dress'),
('Black Night', 'Prom dress', 600, '6380325.png', 'A beautifull black dress'),
('Red Velvet', 'Prom dress', 400,  'red.png', 'A beautifull red velvet dress');
```

this will automatically insert value for column ID.